# How i can set path in ruby File

Tags: ruby, file

i dont not how set path for my File in ruby.

this is my  code in ruby class

```
tmp_file = File.new('name', "w+")

      tmp_file.path(Pathname.new("/public/word_tempate"))
```

How i can set path for write file in ruby?.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If you want to write a file as `/public/word_template/name` you should just `File.new('/public/word_template/name', "w+")` then.

Comment: Thanks a lot Katafrakt your response work for me. Please if would you like to write your response for vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a file as `/public/word_template/name` you should just include it in the `File` initializer like this:

```
File.new('/public/word_template/name', 'w+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path with initializing the File object:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> tmp_file = File.new('/tmp/name', "w+")
=> #<File:/tmp/name>
irb(main):002:0> tmp_file.puts "hi"
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> tmp_file.close
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> ^D
$ cat /tmp/name
hi
$
```